# Bootstrap menu animation 'x' dont toggle to reset

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, animation, togglebutton

I have a simple problem to solve, been trying to solve it for 2 days in row now, searching for answer with no luck.

The problem is navbar-toggle button (bootstrap menu button in mobile size window)
the animation when clicking the button is working correctly but, when i try to close menu with navbar-toggle (x) button when open, the (x) in the button doesn't reset to rotate(0) in css file.

Example of working bootstrap menu animation button
http://iwebdesign.se/bare/

My button with the problem
http://iwebdesign.se/

I dont know where the problem might be so therefor i dont paste any code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the button remains the focussed element.

EDIT:
I think this part is making it not turn back to normal:

```
header .navbar-iwebdesign .navbar-toggle:focus .top-bar
    {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 15% 85%; /* chrome */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    }
header .navbar-iwebdesign .navbar-toggle:focus .middle-bar-transition-new
    {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 10.5px -1.5px; /* chrome */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0.5;
    }

header .navbar-iwebdesign .navbar-toggle:focus .bottom-bar
    {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 11% 10%; /* chrome */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    }
```

If I were you, I would use jQuery to toggle a class instead.

EDIT:
Just add this to your menu.js:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

and change the above selectors in animation.css to:

```
header .navbar-iwebdesign .navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar
header .navbar-iwebdesign .navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar-transition-new
header .navbar-iwebdesign .navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar
```

Comment: Thanks, I already know that, but what can I do instead? I think I'm making this too difficult, but it seems to be so easy, I done it with the bare bootstrap file but not working with mine.

Comment: Thanks, but I try to get it work with bootstrap js because it already works good.

Comment: Seems like there is jQuery running too, follow my steps above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I solve it like this


$('document').ready(function() {
    if ($('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function() { 
                $('.collapse, #mainContainer').toggleClass('in');
    $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
            }));
});

I didnt get the animation to work but thats minor problem for now :) Cheers!